# Aggregate string in array list java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an Arraylist of string arrays, already filled by the values below (columns and row)

```
{"name","sname","Id1","Id2","type","LDP","oldvalue","newvalue"}
{"test1","abc","20","50","t1","SD1","0","1"}
{"test2","znc","21","23","t1","SF5","3","4"}
{"test1","abc","20","50","t1","SD3","0","1"}
{"test1","HJc","53","50","t1","SD3","0","1"}
{"test2","znc","21","23","t1","SF1","1","6"}
{"test1","abc","20","50","t1","SD5","2","19"}
{"test3","ldb","19","54","t1","SR51","6","1"}
{"test2","znc","21","23","t1","SF12","17","36"}
{"test3","ldb","19","54","t1","SR44","19","31"}
{"test4","lYI","76","56","t1","TB77","54","87"}
```

I want have a new Arraylist by sorting this current Arraylist and get the lines with the same keys (Order by : name,sname,Id1,Id2,type), concatenate their values in one column (separated by ;) in one line.

Expected output:

```
{"name","sname","Id1","Id2","type","Comment"}
{"test1","abc","20","50","t1","SD1,0,1; SD3,0,1; SD5,2,19"}
{"test1","HJc","53","50","t1","SD3,0,1"}
{"test2","znc","21","23","t1","SF5,3,4; SF1,1,6; SF12,17,36"}
{"test3","ldb","19","54","t1","SR44,19,31;SR51,6,1 }
{"test4","lYI","76","56","t1","TB77,54,87"}
```

My Arraylist is generated from a result query:

```
 // header
     String[] myString0 = {"name","sname","Id1","Id2","type","LDP","oldvalue","newvalue"};
    //lines
     while (rset.next()) {

                                String name = rset.getString("name");
                                String sname = rset.getString("sname");
                                String Id1 = rset.getString("Id1");
                                String Id2 = rset.getString("Id2");
                                String type = rset.getString("type");
                                String LDP = rset.getString("LDP");
                                String oldvalue = rset.getString("oldvalue");
                                String newvalue = rset.getString("newvalue");

                                String[] myString1 = {name, sname, Id1, Id2, "type", LDP, oldvalue, newvalue};

                                outerArr.add(myString1);// my Arraylist
                            }
                        }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your example is fuzzy (to me?). How do you mean order. Order by what? How to concatenate the values? Please describe these things.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, order by name,sname,Id1,Id2,type ( as key)

Comment: One approach would be to create an class representing your key. Say that's MyKey. Now you could create a HashMap<MyKey,List<String[]>>. Add each row to a list in the map, creating an entry if necessary. Now just iterate over the entries in the map. For each entry, create your summary line from the records in that entry's list.

Comment: Why is this JSON, and not CSV?

Comment: you just omit item repetition when all of the records contain the same value in the field? why `{"test1","abc","20","50","t1","SD1,0,1; SD3,0,1; SD5,2,19"}` and not `{"test1","abc","20","50","t1","SD1;SD3;SD5","0;0;1","1;1;19"}`? I don't understand the concatenation logic.

Comment: This is An Arraylist not csv.

Comment: @TheBitman: The logic of concatenation is:
input 
A,B,C,D,1,2,3
A,B,C,D,2,3,4

output

A,B,C,D,"1,2,3; 2,3,4"

Comment: i saw that before. but where are the concatenated COLUMNS? there are concatenated record fragments. how would you want to access the field values by keys from the output?

Comment: @TheBitman: the concatenated column are "LDP","oldvalue","newvalue". I want to concatenate this column in One separated by , or another separator.   input A,B,C,D,1,2,3 A,B,C,D,2,3,4 output A,B,C,D,"1;2;3|2;3;4"

Comment: Is this a SQL result set? Why not group and order in your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using Streams, with a bit of help from Guava's [`Ordering`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) utility:

```
public static List<String[]> aggregate(List<String[]> data) {
    List<String[]> aggregated = data.stream()
            .skip(1)
            .map(Arrays::asList)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    a -> a.subList(0, 5),
                    () -> new TreeMap<>(
                            Ordering.from(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
                                    .lexicographical()),
                    Collectors.mapping(
                            a -> String.join(",", a.subList(5, 8)),
                            Collectors.joining("; "))))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> Stream.concat(
                    e.getKey().stream(),
                    Stream.of(e.getValue())))
            .map(s -> s.toArray(String[]::new))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

    aggregated.add(0, new String[] {"name","sname","Id1","Id2","type","Comment"});

    return aggregated;
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String[]> data = Arrays.asList(new String[][] {
            {"name","sname","Id1","Id2","type","LDP","oldvalue","newvalue"},
            {"test1","abc","20","50","t1","SD1","0","1"},
            {"test2","znc","21","23","t1","SF5","3","4"},
            {"test1","abc","20","50","t1","SD3","0","1"},
            {"test1","HJc","53","50","t1","SD3","0","1"},
            {"test2","znc","21","23","t1","SF1","1","6"},
            {"test1","abc","20","50","t1","SD5","2","19"},
            {"test3","ldb","19","54","t1","SR51","6","1"},
            {"test2","znc","21","23","t1","SF12","17","36"},
            {"test3","ldb","19","54","t1","SR44","19","31"},
            {"test4","lYI","76","56","t1","TB77","54","87"}
    });

    aggregate(data)
            .stream()
            .map(Arrays::toString)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
[name, sname, Id1, Id2, type, Comment]
[test1, abc, 20, 50, t1, SD1,0,1; SD3,0,1; SD5,2,19]
[test1, HJc, 53, 50, t1, SD3,0,1]
[test2, znc, 21, 23, t1, SF5,3,4; SF1,1,6; SF12,17,36]
[test3, ldb, 19, 54, t1, SR51,6,1; SR44,19,31]
[test4, lYI, 76, 56, t1, TB77,54,87]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  is expected solution!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your own key class for the first 5 columns, or concatenate them into a string (may or may not be adequate for your use case).
2. Add everything to a map keyed by your key class, with a String, StringBuilder, or List for your values / concatenated fields
3. After you have parsed all the data into the map, then iterate the map to put everything back into a list, looping to concatenate the values for each key
4. Sort the new list according to sorting preferences (or alternatively, maintain a sorted map using a LinkedHashMap initially).

The above is probably easier to do using a guava [ArrayListMultiMap](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html).

E.g. something like

```
// for each row...
myArrayListMultiMap.put(new MyKey(name, sname, id1, id2, type), LDP + "," + oldValue + "," + newValue);

// then
for (MyKey key : myArrayListMultiMap.keySet()) {
    List<String> values = myArrayListMultiMap.get(key);
    String concatenated = StringUtils.join(values, ";");
    myList.add(new Row(entry.getKey(), concatenated));
}

Collections.sort(myList, myComparator);
```

**Important note**: make sure that your MyKey class implements `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!